# SqlDataAdapter has some of the functions like AddToBatch(), ClearBatch(), ExecuteBatch(). What are they used for?

Tags: asp.net

I need an example to understand this or some good articles would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute a number of commands in one batch, you can add them to a batch then execute it.

A batch is simply a collection of commands - sometimes you may want to send them all together to the database instead of one at a time.

Comment: @Chandan Khatwani - See this article for examples: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/mfc_database/ado/article.php/c6273/

Comment: actually , I dont see the AddToBatch method coming in the intellisense

Comment: @ Oded....I have done multiple select queries example. It works fine , but can I do multiple insert statements similarly?  Oh and by the way, articles dont speak about those functions being used

Comment: @Chandan Khatwani - Yes. And mix them. And use updates. And call stored procedures. Any command really.